# Will Java Built on One Linux Distribution Work on All Others?

Tags: java, linux, jlink

If I build a minimized JRE using `jlink` on one distribution (RHEL, Ubuntu, etc), will it work on all other distributions? As a basic test I created a jre on RHEL and it worked fine on Ubuntu, but there are too many variations of distributions for me to test them all. As a general rule of thumb, should I expect java built on any linux system to work on another, assuming the same underlying architecture (amd64, aarch64, etc)?

Comment: In general, yes. You might also need the same libc. But I'm not certain.

Comment: Java runs on practically every device, and as long as you are only using native libraries, yes. It will work on all systems.

Answer (score 2):

All the available evidence indicates that yes, you can expect the application to work on nearly all Linux systems.  A jlink’d image tree has its own `lib` directory which includes a lot of shared libraries.  JVMs are thoroughly tested, and I’m guessing the Linux version was at least fully tested on [the certified system configurations](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-doc-jdk17certconfig.html).

I haven’t examined every single file in a jlink’d image tree in detail, but I have never noticed anything that is particular to any of those Linux distributions.  (I build on Debian.)

Out of curiosity, I did `ldd java` on the stripped-down java binary in my jlink’d application.  It’s a short list:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffecf94b000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f85827ca000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8582795000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f858278f000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f85825ba000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8582816000)
```

(I have omitted libjli.so, which is inside the image tree.)

I assume it will run on any system where those six libraries are present.  I doubt a typical Linux system would lack any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this looks promising!